# Return a dictionary with word and count of the word on unique line

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to print a dictionary with each key and value on a unique line. I have tried .split(",") but found that this doesn't work for lists or dictionaries and am stuck with trying to work around this.
Instead of printing this

```
{'is': 2, 'that': 2, 'the': 2, 'this': 2, 'was': 2, 'way': 2}
```

I am trying to print this:

```
is: 2
that: 2
the: 2
this: 2
was: 2
way: 2
```

Comment: You need a for-loop iterating through the dictionary and printing each entry on its own line.

Comment: And there's no need to create a second dictionary, just loop through `sorted_lst`

Comment: This question has nothing to do with word counts. You're just asking how to print a dictionary with one entry per line. How the dictionary was created is irrelevant.

Comment: `'\n'.join([f'{k}: {v}' for k,v in ur_dict.items()])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print each entry in alphabetical order in the `key: value` format you can look toward the following:

```
import re    
def print_word_counts(filename):
    input_file = open(filename, 'r')
    source_string = input_file.read().lower()
    input_file.close()
    words = re.findall('[a-zA-Z]+', source_string)    

    file_counts = {}
    for word in words:
        file_counts[word] = file_counts.get(word, 0) + 1

    for k,v in sorted(file_counts.items()):
        print(f'{k}: {v}')
```

Note, you don't need to go from `dict()` to `list()` and back, you can get `sorted` dict's `.items()` upfront.

Answer (score 0):

printing the dict:

```
for key, value in the_dict.items():
    print(f"{key}: {value}")
```

which output

```
key1: val1
key2: val2
...: ...
```